# GTK++ Window Confusion

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I am experimenting with GTK++ on Ubuntu and I'm not having much luck. Just for testing purposes, I wanted to see if I could get a Boolean describing whether or not a window is resizable. Here is my code:

```
  #include <gtkmm.h>
  #include <iostream>
  #include "config.h"

 int  main (int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    gboolean isResizable;
    Gtk::Main kit(argc, argv);

    Gtk::Window* main_win = new Gtk::Window (Gtk::WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    main_win->set_title ("gtk-test");
    isResizable = gtk_window_get_resizable(main_win);
    if (main_win)
    {
        kit.run(*main_win);
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

I am getting an error on the line where I set `isResizable` to `gtk_window_get_resizable`.
The error says:

```
    cannot convert 'Gtk::Window*' to GtkWindow* {aka_Gtk_window*} for argument 1
```

Is there a difference between `Gtk::Window` and `GtkWindow*` ? And if so, how would I go about passing in `Gtk::Window` ?

Thanks

Comment: regarding names: the C GTK library is, somewhat confusingly, called "gtk+" (note single +), and the C++ bindings are called "gtk--" or "gtkmm". neither of them is called "gtk++", and when you write that it's not obvious if you intend to refer to the C "gtk+" or the C++ "gtk--".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instread of:

```
gtk_window_get_resizable(main_win);
```

Call:

```
main_win->get_resizable();
```

> Is there a difference between Gtk::Window and GtkWindow* ?

`Gtk::Window` ( and `main_win->get_resizable()` ) is C++ (gtkmm)

`GtkWindow` ( and `gtk_window_get_resizable` ) is C (gtk)

It's easy to cross the two, since gtkmm is a wrapper for gtk, so you have both codebases.

Comment: Ah! Thank You! I didn't realize that I was looking at the gtk reference.